# TypeError, making directory with Python in Maya

Tags: python, typeerror, maya

I am trying to make a folder to save a file in with Python in Maya. However, I am getting an error, of which I am not sure how to solve. (not very experienced in scripting, yet)

This is the code that creates the directory string:
(Maya correctly prints out the DIRECTORY)

```
# Creates a directory to save the .json file to
USERAPPDIR = cmds.internalVar(userAppDir = True)
DIRECTORY = os.path.join(USERAPPDIR, "gradingManager")
print('Maya application directory: ', DIRECTORY)
```

The function that creates the directory is controlled with a button in Maya:

```
    ##########################
    # Safe data in json file #
    ##########################
    cmds.text(label = "")
    cmds.text(label = " Save all results to a .json file for record keeping.",
              font = "boldLabelFont")
    cmds.button(label = "Save to .json file", command = self.save, width = 600)
```

The actual function(s):

```
def save(self, directory=DIRECTORY, *args):
    ######################################################################
    ## This method saves the information gathered above in a .json file ##
    ######################################################################

    # creates a directory
    self.createDir(directory)

    print("saving things")

def createDir(self, directory=DIRECTORY):
    ###################################################################
    ## This function creates a directory for the save functionality. ##
    ###################################################################

    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.mkdir(directory)
```

The error & function it refers to:

```
# Error: TypeError: file C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2020\bin\python27.zip\genericpath.py line 26: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, bool found #

# Does a path exist?
# This is false for dangling symbolic links on systems that support them.
def exists(path):
    """Test whether a path exists.  Returns False for broken symbolic links"""
    try:
        os.stat(path)
    except os.error:
        return False
    return True
```

I hope this is enough information.
I kept the functions as clean as possible so it is clear that the issue comes from checking if the path for the new directory already exists..
If you need any more information, I'll be happy to supply it.

Comment: alwys put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful infomation.

Comment: if FULL error message shows you in which line is problem then you could use `print()` and `print(type())` to check values in variables. It seems you put wrong value in `directory` when you execute `os.path.exists(directory)`. It seems you have value `True/False` instead of expectec `path`. You run this in `save()` which is assigned to `button` - `button(..., command=self.save)` - but I'm not sure if `button` will execute it with expected `path`. It may execute it with totally different values (i.e. with event information) or `save(True)` and you will have `createDir(True)` and `exists(True)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

As far as I can see, this is the full error line I get. It indicates that the error is in line 26 from a document that is installed with Maya / Native Maya file (not sure if that is how you say it..) 
Line 26 in that file is "os.stat(path)", but I included the whole function. (so, this is not my own function but from Maya self)

Comment: The button runs the correct function... when I tell the function to just print something, it does so when I click the button... is that what you mean? 
lastly... it does say that I have a bool instead of a string somewhere.. .but if I hover my mouse over the 'directory' word, it indicated that it is in fact a string...

Comment: did you check `print(directory)` in function `save` ? When you click button then it may run it as `save(True)` but you expect `save(some_path)` or `save()` with default value `DIRECTORY` - and this can make your problem.

Comment: Ah like that.. 
It prints False instead of a path. Why does it do that?

Comment: because you expect too much. Button doesn't know what you want to get in function `save`. Today you want directory but in other program you may expect images from internet. BUT it doesn't work this way. Button sends only values defined by Maya authors - and these values should be described in documentation. I don't know what get button in MAYA but in many GUIs  buttons get information about events - what widget was click, what mouse button was used, what was mouse position, etc. And if you want to get something different then you have to put values directly in function - not as arguments.

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press button then you expect it will run `save(some_path)` or `save()` with default value `DIRECTORY` but it doesn't work this way.

Button executes function with some values predefined by Maya authors. I don't know what values send button in Maya to `save()` but in other GUIs usually it sends event informations - ie. what widget was click, what mouse button was used, what was mouse position, etc.

So it seems button executes `save(True)` or maybe even `save(True, other values)` and this assign `True` to dictionary in your `def save(self, dictionary, ...)` and later it runs `createDir(True) and` exists(True)` and you get error message.

You should use `DIRECTORY` directly inside function.

```
def save(self, *args):

    directory = DIRECTORY

    # creates a directory
    self.createDir(directory)

    print("saving things")
```

And if you have some widget to selecte directory or write manually directory then you would have to also use it inside function

```
def save(self, *args):

    directory = some_widget_to_select_folder.get_selected_folder()
   
    if not directory:
        directory = DIRECTORY

    # creates a directory
    self.createDir(directory)

    print("saving things")
```